# Eclipse-Plugin - How to open a custom progam in a custom view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Basically I want to open a file in a custom program, which I can define, thus I can run a bash terminal for example in the workbench with gvim or vim.

In theory I think, that I need a custom plugin which adds a new entry in the 'Show in' context menu.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Only Eclipse plug-ins can access views/editors, so this would be extremely difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with 3rd party program of generic origin has no common solution as it hardly depends on 3rd party technologies. You need to greatly restrict you scenario to something more specific to find an answer.

Please have a look at Eclipse Remote System Explorer (RSE) https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fgettingstarted%2Fg_start.html that sounds a bit related with what you want to achieve.

Comment: well thank you but I think there are enough informations. gvim/vim open with 'Show in' context menu to open a file in that specific program. The RSE System looks useful but I don't think that this helps with my purpose. I'll looks over it, ty. btw. can't accept your answer as answer :)

Comment: So, the _program_ is something outside the Eclipse Workbench. In this case you can use `org.eclipse.swt.program.Program'  , please have a look here https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fprogram%2FProgram.html